# Query varying multi-level relations in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database-relations

Simulated example. Two mongodb collections, `departments` and `employees`:

**Departments**

```
{ _id: '101' }
{ _id: '102', parent: '101' }
{ _id: '103', parent: '101' }
{ _id: '104', parent: '103' }
```

**Employees**

```
{ _id: '201', department: '101' }
{ _id: '202', department: '102' }
{ _id: '203', department: '102' }
{ _id: '204', department: '103' }
{ _id: '205', department: '104' }
```

How can I query a list of all employees in a department, or any sub department (by the `department.parent` reference property)?

So for the above example, querying for:

- department `101` should give employee documents `201, 202, 203, 204, 205`
- department `102` should give employee documents `202, 203, 204, 205`
- department `103` should give employee documents `204, 205`

If it is not possible to make a query for "any number" of levels in the department tree, one that gives the results for "up to N" levels is fully acceptable.

Comment: It would be hard to do so with your current data structure(doable but not very efficient). I suggest you add children field into department to simulate a tree structure. That would make you life so much easier. Refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Answer (score 0):

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in MongoDb performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database.

In case if we have one level of relationship between our collections then we can $lookup to perform an aggregation on the collections.

Assuming we have one level of relationship(say one department to an Employee) in the given sample collection then the aggregate query is

```
db.department.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "employees",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "department",
          as: "result"
        }
   }
])
```

_id from the Department collection is only taken for aggregation and the parent department relationship is not taken for aggregation

and the result on the sample collection given above is

```
{
        "_id" : "101",
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "201",
                        "department" : "101"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "102",
        "parent" : "101",
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "202",
                        "department" : "102"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "203",
                        "department" : "102"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "103",
        "parent" : "101",
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "204",
                        "department" : "103"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "104",
        "parent" : "103",
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "205",
                        "department" : "104"
                }
        ]
}
```

Please note that MongoDB is a NoSQL database and it is a good practice to design our collection schema in such a way that there is no or very less relationship between collections.